# Automate running files in R

Tags: r, automation

I need to automate a process in R. Basically I have a an R script (I will call it **R1**) that needs three separate files to run. These three files are the results output of one trial in my study.

*For each run of R1 on these three files*, I obtain the summary results for one trial, in a csv file, plus 32 graphs for each decision point in the trial.

*One subject goes through nine trials*.

I was thinking about putting all the files originally generated by one subject in one big folder, so I will have 27 files (three files times nine trials). This way I won't have to change working directory multiple times (I wonder if there is a way to have R open a folder with a certain name as directory, run a scripts, move the directory to the next folder, run the script again...)

*The nine trials are specified by the labels:* `AA AB AM BA BB BM MA MB MM`.

So for `subject 1`, `trial 1`, I will have three files with the ending `…mov1_AA`

*After a run of the three files corresponding to one trial, R should save the csv summary output in a separate folder called `“summary_mov1”` and name the file `summary_mov1_AA`, and so on. R should save the 32 graphs in a different folder, named `mov1_graphs`, `graph1_mov1_AA`, `graph1_mov1_AB` and so on*.

Ideally, after the script has gone through the nine trials, another R script called **R2** should take the nine CSV files and build some graphs out of them.

Once R has run the R1 script nine times, I would proceed to a new subject.

So basically:

- use R1 with three `mov1` files, get a summary csv file in a summary folder (plus 32 graphs in a different folder).
- do this nine times. Once one gets the nine CSV summary files in the same folder, use R2 to average them and build a graph.
- Then do this for each subject (right now I have 7).

I have never done this type of automation so I am a bit lost. Any suggestions? Any examples you can point me to? Which would be the best workflow? At which level should I automate and which things should I rather do by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does not answer your question in terms of all the names you use, since I did not quite get all the combinations you need. However, the following code demonstrates how you could basically create directories, read/wite csv files, write plots into files, etc. and loop over various files. I have only used some nonsense data, plots, etc. for the purpose of demonstration (in future questions please try to provide some exemplary data.). You will have to adapt the calculations and plotting to your needs. Please also note that you might use different data structures for storing objects, I just used lists here for the simple example.

```
# make sure you are in a safe directory!
# define dirs
dir_project = "test"
dirs = list(
dir_project = dir_project
,dir_data = paste0(dir_project, "/data")
,dir_summary = paste0(dir_project, "/summary")
,dir_plots= paste0(dir_project, "/plots")
)
# create dirs
lapply(dirs, dir.create)
# create some exemplary data and write it in dir
m = matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
data = list(m1 = m, m2 = m, m3 = m
            ,n1 = m, n2 = m, n3 = m)
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
  write.csv(data[[i]], file = paste0(dirs[["dir_data"]], "/", names(data[i]), ".csv"))  
}

# read data as if it were your files 
# assuming that the desired patterns of the filenames are known
# you can loop over them
patterns = c("m", "n")
for (p in patterns) {
files = list.files(dirs[["dir_data"]], pattern = paste0(p, "\\d.csv"), full.names = T)
data = lapply(files, read.csv)
names(data) = gsub(".csv", "", basename(files), fixed = T)
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
  png(file = paste0(dirs[["dir_plots"]], "/", names(data)[i],  "_plot.png"))
  plot(data[[i]])
  #turn off the graphics device
  dev.off()
}
# do some summary thing - of course, this depends on what you want as summary
# here I just bind all matrices together and call the standard summary()
data_summary = do.call(rbind, data)
#      X V1 V2
# m1.1 1  1  3
# m1.2 2  2  4
# m2.1 1  1  3
# m2.2 2  2  4
# m3.1 1  1  3
# m3.2 2  2  4
write.csv(as.data.frame(summary(data_summary))
          , file = paste0(dirs[["dir_summary"]], "/", paste0(names(data), collapse = "_"), "_summary.csv")) 
}

# check output
list.files(dirs[["dir_plots"]])
# [1] "m1_plot.png" "m2_plot.png" "m3_plot.png"
# [4] "n1_plot.png" "n2_plot.png" "n3_plot.png"
list.files(dirs[["dir_summary"]])
# [1] "m1_m2_m3_summary.csv" "n1_n2_n3_summary.csv"
read.csv("test/summary/m1_m2_m3_summary.csv")
# X Var1     Var2          Freq
# 1   1   NA        X Min.   :1.0  
# 2   2   NA        X 1st Qu.:1.0  
# 3   3   NA        X Median :1.5  
# 4   4   NA        X Mean   :1.5  
# 5   5   NA        X 3rd Qu.:2.0  
# 6   6   NA        X Max.   :2.0  
# 7   7   NA       V1 Min.   :1.0  
# 8   8   NA       V1 1st Qu.:1.0  
# 9   9   NA       V1 Median :1.5  
# 10 10   NA       V1 Mean   :1.5  
# 11 11   NA       V1 3rd Qu.:2.0  
# 12 12   NA       V1 Max.   :2.0  
# 13 13   NA       V2 Min.   :3.0  
# 14 14   NA       V2 1st Qu.:3.0  
# 15 15   NA       V2 Median :3.5  
# 16 16   NA       V2 Mean   :3.5  
# 17 17   NA       V2 3rd Qu.:4.0  
# 18 18   NA       V2 Max.   :4.0 

# delete the test directory and all data (just to have a clean example here)
unlink("test", recursive = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed example. I have tested out the file and it works great. I have made some changes to adjust the example to my situation, and I would like to post a follow-up question, but I am not sure how to do it here. Should I post another answer to the main question with the modified code?

Comment: Good to know it works. In case you do not get a better answer, I would kindly ask considering to accept the answer. Concerning a follow up question it depends what its about. if its just a refinement of your question you can simply edit it, especially since there is only one answer yet. however, if its really a new issue that could be asked independently from the current question, i would create a new one and reference this one here.

Comment: Thanks. If I edit the question though, let's say using your code, then your answer will be outdated, would that be OK? The update is about the file numbering etc.

Comment: OK, I will write a new question. I will refer to your code.

Comment: I wrote an updated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575960/how-to-loop-twice-over-files-names-in-r)